# Getting negative address in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, *p;
    p = a;
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", p, *p);
    return 0;
}
```

When I executed this code, I got a negative value for p. I have studied that address cannot be negative. Then why I have got a negative value

Comment: "_address cannot be negative_" - sure they can. Your code has undefined behavior though, so you shouldn't draw any conclusion from its output.

Comment: @Mat; Any example of negative address?

Comment: @haccks: half the address space on x86_64 (unless you want to treat them all as unsigned, obviously)

Comment: You may use `%u` to printf unsigned values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pointers, use `%p` with `printf()`:

```
int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, *p;
p = a;
printf("%p\n%d", (void *)p, *p);
```

Also make sure your comiler warnings are at the highest level. You should get a warning for using `%d` with a pointer then:

```
warning <code>: 'printf'  : '%d' in format string conflicts with argument 1 of type 'int *'
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `%d` is not the correct format specifier to handle a *pointer* (address). You should be using `%p` and cast the corresponding argument to `void*` for printing an address. Using wrong argument type for a particular format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

   To quote `C11` chapter §7.21.6.1

   > [...] If any argument is
   >   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
   >   undefined.
2. In this code, `*p` does not denote an address, anyway.
3. You cannot print an array by just using the `%d`s in a single format string. You need to have a loop. In your code,

   ```
   printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", p, *p);
   ```

   the format string expects 5 `int`s as argument, while you supply only a pointer and an `int`. FWIW, supplying insufficient argument for supplied conversion specifiers invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), too. Quoting the same standard,

   > [...] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
   >   undefined. [...]

To elaborate, replace

```
 printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", p, *p);
```

by

```
 for (i= 0; i < 5; i++, p++)
 printf("%d %p\n", *p, (void *)p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mis-matched `printf()` specifiers and arguments

`printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", p, *p);` expects 5 `int`.  Code is supplying a `int *` and `int`.  Result: undefined behavior.

Instead:

```
printf("Pointer %p\nValue: %d\n", (void *) p, *p);
```